# Why is the maximum value of the light sensor from my phone stuck at 85745.0lx?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sensors, cyanogenmod

My lightsensor of my Samsung Galaxy S3 doesn't return good values.
I tested it in different places, p.E. outside in the sun or indoor with and without light.

The value outside was a bit confusing because the result was the proper value of 85745.0lx. This value is first of all 4 times higher than in comparison with my tablet. At a second Samsung S3 (with Stock-OS) it was about 18'000 lux. Second point: it was a fix value, it didn't change between ~200lux all the time.

After the tests I tried to find out, why that happend. The function `maxvalue = light.getMaxumumRange();` shows me, that the maximum value of the light sensor is 121240.0 lx.
Could it be, that this value is, because I have an custom rom on my phone ([Team UB](https://plus.google.com/communities/112536693347437354097))? Or does anyone know an other reason for this difference?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it could be because you have a custom ROM on your phone. Most likely the ROM has a buggy or poorly integrated touchscreen driver. Drivers in custom ROMs often don't perform correctly, especially in unofficial or pre-release builds, and especially with non-essential functionality like light sensors.